# loop over expression in Mathematica

Tags: loops, for-loop, wolfram-mathematica

I have an expression containing 3 variables. Two of which are datasets ( p and k)
I want to compute this expression for every p and k and have a list of sigma.
I am very basic at Mathematica. How can I write a loop over this expression for the data set to have a list of sigma?

```
p = Import["C:\\Users\\Maryestein\\onlyp.csv", "Dataset"]
K = Import["C:\\Users\\Maryestein\\onlyk.csv", "Dataset"]

Sigma_i^2 = 
 9/(2*Pi^2)* [Sin[K_i*R] - K_i*R*Cos[K_i*R]]^2/(K_i*R)^6*p_i*
  K_i^2*(K_i - K_ (i - 1))
```

Comment: `[ and ]` are only used around function arguments in Mathematica, not to be used to group expressions in a different way from `( and )` Next `_` is only used for pattern matching in Mathematica and not to make variable names look different.  If you could include the output for very small simple examples from reading your two .csv files that might help ensure the answer is more likely correct, perhaps even including what you would want the output to be for these very simple input files. With that someone could likely write a line of code that would do what you want.

Comment: Another way that might do what you mean `p={a,b,c,d,e,f,g};k={t,u,v,w,x,y,z};sigma=Table[ 9/(2*Pi^2)*(Sin[k[[i]]*r]-k[[i]]*r*Cos[k[[i]]*r])^2/(k[[i]]*r)^6*p[[i]]*k[[i]]^2*(k[[i]]-k[[i-1]]),{i,2,Length[p]}]` Lists/datasets index starting with 1, not with zero, and I think you are subtracting the current item in k from the previous item in k, so this starts with at the second item in p and k to provide a previous item to subtract the first time. I substituted letters for your data so you might be able to look at the result to try to see what steps it did. Let me know if this still isn't right

Answer (score 0):

Here are two toy working examples depending on what you exactly want.
They should be easy to adapt to your
precise function.  pi and Ki are dummy variables used for legibility.

If you want to make a computation for every possible
couple of something in p and something in K

```
p = {10, 20, 30};
K = {.1, .2, .3, .4};
Outer[Function[{pi, Ki}, Ki + pi ], p, K, 1]
```

output

```
{{10.1, 10.2, 10.3, 10.4}, {20.1, 20.2, 
  20.3, 20.4}, {30.1, 30.2, 30.3, 30.4}}
```

If your two lists are of the same length and are meant to
be used in parallel (as your use of a common indice suggests)

```
p = {10, 20, 30, 30};
K = {.1, .2, .3, .4};
MapThread[Function[{pi, Ki}, Ki + pi], {p, K}, 1]
```

output

```
{10.1, 20.2, 30.3, 30.4}
```